# Can't unwrap optional. No UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, xcode6

I've a table view that has a custom table view cell in it. My problem is that when I try and assign a value to a variable in the custom `UITableViewCell` I get the stated error. Now, I think its because the said variable is not initialised, but it got me completely stumped.

This is the custom table cell:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class LocationGeographyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell
{
    //@IBOutlet var Map : MKMapView;

    @IBOutlet var AddressLine1 : UILabel;
    @IBOutlet var AddressLine2 : UILabel;
    @IBOutlet var County : UILabel;
    @IBOutlet var Postcode : UILabel;
    @IBOutlet var Telephone : UILabel;

    var location = VisitedLocation();

    func Build(location:VisitedLocation) -> Void
    {
        self.location = location;

        AddressLine1.text = "test";
    }
}
```

My cell for row at index path is:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!
    {

        var addressCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ContactDetail") as? LocationGeographyTableViewCell;

        if !addressCell
        {
            addressCell = LocationGeographyTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: "ContactDetail");
        }

        addressCell!.Build(Location);

        return addressCell;
    }
```

As I say I'm completely baffled, the Build function calls the correct function in the `UITableViewCell`.

Any help will be gratefully appreciated.

Ta

Comment: How is the cell with the id "ContactDetail" setup?

Comment: What is `Location` that you are passing to your `Build` function in the second code snippet?

Comment: Location is just a flat object, I'm not using it at present. Doing a println on an entity in it outputs the correct value.

Comment: The ContailDetail cell - style:Custom, the rest is standard for a new tableviewcell. Custom class is set to LocationGeographyTableViewCell.

Comment: The tableviewcell is in a sectioned table, but setting the construction of the tableview cell to look for the correct section doesn't make a difference. I've changed the 'Build' method to set the custom table cell to set the 'text' attribute and this correctly outputs the set text. It is like the UILabel outlets are not initialised. These are currently bound in the Storyboard

Comment: So you are having problems with `AddressLine1`? Not your `location` variable? Some more details would be nice....

Comment: I think, as I understand it, AddressLine1 (and all the other outlets) have not been initialised. I am stumped as to how to initialise them as I thought this would be done on the fly.

Comment: Hmm... that seems weird to me, and unlikely. Let me setup a test project.

Answer (score 0):

I just made a simple project with your code, and I have a nil "AddressLine1" label, which causes the same error you have. I assume we have the same problem.

I solved it by adding the identifier "ContactDetail" to the prototype cell in my storyboard.

I also suggest that you change your code a little :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {        
    // This newer API ensures that you always get a cell, so no need for optionals. 
    // Also note the "let" that is preferred since you don't plan on changing addressCell
    let addressCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ContactDetail", forIndexPath: indexPath) as LocationGeographyTableViewCell; 

    //addressCell.Build(Location); // the cell is a view, views should not know about model objects

    addressCell.AddressLine1 = Location.addressLine1
    // ... same for all labels, or do all that in a "configureCell" function

    return addressCell;
}
```

Comment: I wonder - why views shouldn't know about model objects? That would make the architecture a lot more complicated.

Comment: This is the way the MVC pattern is described. The controller should be the link between the views and the model. One advantage is that you can reuse your views between projects, since they don't depend on the model. Other patterns exist (you can take a look at MVVM, which is a bit different), but MVC is still the standard given by Apple.

Comment: I think I mis-wrote my previous comment, but never mind. The stated code works perfectly fine one my initial view, but when I push a new controller using a segue the custom tableview cell has all the Optional.Nil problem. All the identifiers are correct, I've double, triple and quadrupal checked that it is setup the same as the parent controller but I get the stated error.

Comment: Do you think you could make your project public, or a simple version that reproduces the problem so that we can investigate with the actual code?

Comment: I've put it in drop box: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yg9qe3gl9rjyaw1/Visited.zip) The LocationGeographyTableViewCell is where it throws the error, click on a cell on the first tableview and it pushes a segue and then breaks. Thanks Mat

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it. Instead of using the storyboard to define the UITableViewCell (as I'd done in the parent view controller) I created a Xib with the content and wired that up to the cell's class, referenced it in the TableViewController and allocated it in the cell created method.

```
viewDidLoad()
{
        var nib = UINib(nibName: "LocationTableViewCell", bundle: nil)

        tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "locationCell")  
}

var cell:LocationGeographyTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("locationCell") as LocationGeographyTableViewCell
cell.AddressLine1.text = "teetetette";
return cell;
```